# Calculating distance with Euclidean, Manhattan, and Chebyshev in C#

Tags: c#, mathematics

I am by no means proficient at being able to take mathematical concepts and converting them to code. I was wondering if you guys could look at it and make suggestions on how I could fix it or if my thinking is correct on these. I used a combination of the wikipedia pages for each of these as well as http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html to come up with my solutions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Algorithms
{
    public static class Heuristics
    {
        // implementation for integer based Manhattan Distance
        public static int ManhattanDistance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
        {
            return Math.Abs(x1 - x2) + Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
        }

        // implementation for floating-point  Manhattan Distance
        public static float ManhattanDistance(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2)
        {
            return Math.Abs(x1 - x2) + Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
        }

        // implementation for integer based Euclidean Distance
        public static int EuclideanDistance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
        {
            int square = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
            return square;
        }

        // implementation for floating-point EuclideanDistance
        public static float EuclideanDistance(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2)
        {
            float square = (x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2);
            return square;
        }

        // implementation for integer based Chebyshev Distance
        public static int ChebyshevDistance(int dx, int dy)
        {
            // not quite sure if the math is correct here
            return 1 * (dx + dy) + (1 - 2 * 1) * (dx - dy);
        }

        // implementation for floating-point Chebyshev Distance
        public static float ChebyshevDistance(float dx, float dy)
        {
            // not quite sure if the math is correct here
            return 1 * (dx + dy) + (1 - 2 * 1) * (dx - dy);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with some housekeeping. You're not using these using so they should be removed:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

---

Your namespace is far too generic - it's much better than `ConsoleApplication1` but you should use something like `<Company>.<Product>.<Feature>` in your real app.

---

Your method names should be verb phrases `ManhattanDistance` should be `CalculateManhattanDistance` (and likewise for the others).

---

Why does your `ChebyshevDistance` take different parameters to the others? That seems unfriendly in the API design.

---

You should add documentation comments rather than simple comments to explain what a method does.

e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the Manhattan distance between the two points.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x1">The first x coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="x2">The second x coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="y1">The first y coordinate.</param>
/// <param name="y2">The second y coordinate.</param>
/// <returns>The Manhattan distance between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)</returns>
public static int CalculateManhattanDistance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    return Math.Abs(x1 - x2) + Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
}
```

I'd also consider swapping the order of the parameters so you specify `x1, y1, x2, y2` or using `Point` and `PointF` instead.

---

Now that's out of the way... `ManhattanDistance` looks correct.

---

`EuclideanDistance` is missing the final square root. The article you've linked to explains why that's bad:

> I’ve seen several A* web pages recommend that you avoid the expensive square root in the Euclidean distance by just using distance-squared
>   [snipped pseudocode]
>   Do not do this! This definitely runs into the scale problem. The scale of g and h need to match, because you’re adding them together to form f. When A* computes f(n) = g(n) + h(n), the square of distance will be much higher than the cost g and you will end up with an overestimating heuristic. For longer distances, this will approach the extreme of g(n) not contributing to f(n), and A* will degrade into Greedy Best-First-Search.

---

According to the [Chebyshev distance Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance), in the Cartesian plane it's simply:

```
max(|x2 - x1|, |y2 - y1|)
```

Making it:

```
public static int CalculateChebyshevDistance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    return Math.Max(Math.Abs(x2 - x1), Math.Abs(y2 - y1));
}
```

Although, following the article you linked your result should be:

```
public static int CalculateChebyshevDistance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    var dx = Math.Abs(x2 - x1);
    var dy = Math.Abs(y2 - y1);
    return (dx + dy) - Math.Min(dx, dy);
}
```

<strike>I can't see how to prove that they're equivalent... If anyone can, I'd be interested to see it!</strike>

They are obviously equivalent... If you add the `dx` and `dy` together and then subtract the smaller of the two you are obviously left with just the bigger value i.e. the max of `dx` and `dy`.